# radeon x1550 catalyst 13.4 supported?

Tags: drivers, ati, 64-bit, compatibility

I am trying to install a proprietary driver and the AMD web site tells me to use Catalyst driver 9.3. I want the newest version of the driver I can get for this graphics card so will 13.4 work or will I have to use 9.3? also I am using 13.04 and is there anything else I should know about a non stock driver install and use?

Any help I can get will be greatly appreciated as I am only a few months new to Ubuntu and Linux in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The x1550 is no longer supported by the standard driver. You will need to either:

- Use the open source driver.
- Use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx?field.series_filter=raring) to downgrade your X server and install the driver.
- Wait for an update to the legacy driver.

### For the PPA option:

Run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
```

Then restart your computer.

### To Undo

Install ppa-purge:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Then run:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:makson96/fglrx
```

---

P.S. unless AMD wises up, quits being silly, and changes their ways, no driver above 13.1 will support older cards such as the x1550 or HD 3450.

Comment: I have messed up my tower several times already trying to get this right so could you please give me the command for undoing this so I can write it down ahead of time as this is my only data connection ..better be safe than sorry

Comment: I have messed up my tower several times already trying to get this right so could you please give me the command for undoing this just incase there are any problems so I can write it down ahead of time as this is my only data connection ..better be safe than sorry @RolandiXor